# Bootstrap datetimepicker is not working on first click

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datetimepicker

If I select any year in Bootstrap `datetimepicker`, for first time it is taking current year, same as if I click any month in first time, its taking current month.
         For example, If I open `datetimepicker` and I select year 2000, but first time it is showing year 2015 only. Again if I choose 2000 means it is working. Same as month also, If I select any month, for first time its taking current month "February". After than its working. How can I resolve this issue?

The following code I am using.

```js
  
var click = 0;
        var click1 = 0;
        var rowIndx = this.id.substring(this.id.length,this.id.length - 1 );
        var d = new Date();
        var month = d.getMonth();
        var day = d.getDate();
        var year = d.getFullYear();
               
     $('#datetimepicker'+rowIndx).datetimepicker({
      format : "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm",        
                    pickSeconds:false,   
     }).on("show",function(e) {
     if($("#fromdate"+ rowIndx).val() == ""){
     $('#datetimepicker'+rowIndx).datetimepicker("setDate", "");              
     }               
     }).on('changeDate', function(e) {                
     if(data[rowIndx]["from_date"] == "") {
     if(click == 0){
     $('#datetimepicker'+rowIndx).data('datetimepicker').setLocalDate(new Date(year, month, day, 00, 00));       
     }
     click = 1;
     }
     });
```

Whatever I will select, the same day month and year will be display on textbox.

Please help me how can I do this?

Comment: Your Snippet doesn't show anything except textbox

Comment: Now In this code,If I add new row Is this possible to set default time "00:00". It wont be affect the existing time. ChangeDate function I am writing that condition. Is any other way is there to achieve this?

Comment: Try once then tell what are the changes